# Changing an IntelliJ keyboard shortcut that is 'Still not loaded'

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts

So I try to get a Visual-Studio-With-Resharper-esque keyboard shortcut scheme in IntelliJ, which involves assigning <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>,  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> to "Refactor > Rename". I'm not allowed. Reason: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> is "Assigned to [Console.TableResult.Reload] which is still not loaded".

How can I remove the assignment from a function that is "not loaded"? Why is it not loaded and how do I load it?

Answer (score 0):

Some actions are added dynamically, e.g. when you activate version control, corresponding actions are added in different menus, etc. That's why sometimes IDEA knows that actions with dedicated shortcuts may be added, but may be not. It warns about such a situation. The message is not easy to read nor to understand though. Will be fixed ASAP.

Comment: ok cool. In this particular case, do you know what "Console.TableResult.Reload" is?

Comment: I had the same problem with remapping a different keystroke. (Cmd+;, which is mapped to Show Project Structure--also "not loaded.") It turns out if you just remap the key anyway, it asks you if you want to remove the conflicting binding. You can click "Yes."